# android studio disable days from date picker

Tags: java, android, datetime, datepicker, android-calendar

I want to disable some day from date picker
I have an array that store the days I want to disable.

I have this code to disable the days from calendar

```
    for (Calendar loopdate = min_date_c;
                     min_date_c.before(max_date_c);
                     min_date_c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), loopdate = min_date_c) {
                    int dayOfWeek = loopdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


                    if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                        Calendar[] disabledDays = new Calendar[1];
                        disabledDays[0] = loopdate;
                        datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
                    }
                }
```

and I tried this code to disable days that are stored in the arraylist, but it does not work. It only disables the first item from the arraylist

```
   ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
            a.add(1);  //saturday
            a.add(2);  //sunday
            a.add(3);  //monday
            int day;


            for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++) {

                day=(Integer)a.get(i);



                for (Calendar loopdate = min_date_c;
                     min_date_c.before(max_date_c);
                     min_date_c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), loopdate = min_date_c) {
                    int dayOfWeek = loopdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);



                    if (day == 1) {
                        System.out.println(day);
                        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                            Calendar[] disabledDays = new Calendar[1];
                            disabledDays[0] = loopdate;
                            datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
                        }
                    }

                  else  if (day==2) {
                        System.out.println(day);

                        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                            Calendar[] disabledDays = new Calendar[1];
                            disabledDays[0] = loopdate;
                            datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
                        }
                    }

                   else if (day==3) {
                        System.out.println(day);
                        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
                            Calendar[] disabledDays = new Calendar[1];
                            disabledDays[0] = loopdate;
                            datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
                        }
                    }


                }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: edited for better readability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the material design component [`MaterialDatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker) to control the calendar more easily and efficiently; it allows you to control every single day of the calendar by implementing [`CalendarConstraints.DateValidator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints.DateValidator) interface.

Specificlly in your issue, you need to disable particular days; so, you will create a class that implements `CalendarConstraints.DateValidator`, and then:

- Override the needed methods, and build a Parcelable

> `CalendarConstraints.DateValidator` Extends `Parcelable` in order to maintain the `DateValidator` across
>   device configuration changes. `Parcelable` breaks when passed between
>   processes.

- Override `isValid(long date)` method that validates every single date
  in the calendar and returns a `boolean` that indicates whether this
  date is valid or not, in other meaning if the date is enabled or disabled/dimmed; so, if a date is valid, then it returns true, and that date will be enabled for selection by the user.

Hereunder, I will provide a Validator that disable **Mondays** in **Feb.2020**; and you can easily disable any days the same manner.

**Implementing `CalendarConstraints.DateValidator`:**

```
static class MondaysOutValidator implements CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {

    int mYear, mMonth, mDayOfWeek;

    MondaysOutValidator(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = month;
        mDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    MondaysOutValidator(Parcel parcel) {
        mYear = parcel.readInt();
        mMonth = parcel.readInt();
        mDayOfWeek = parcel.readInt();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(long date) {

        List<Integer> allXDayOfMonth = getAllXDayOfMonth(mYear, mMonth, mDayOfWeek);

        boolean isValidDays = false;
        for (int xDay : allXDayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            ArrayList<Long> minDate = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Long> maxDate = new ArrayList<>();
            calendarStart.set(mYear, mMonth, xDay - 1);
            calendarEnd.set(mYear, mMonth, xDay);
            minDate.add(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
            maxDate.add(calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis());
            isValidDays = isValidDays || !(minDate.get(0) > date || maxDate.get(0) < date);
        }

        return !isValidDays;

    }


    private static int getFirstXDayOfMonth(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek) {
        Calendar cacheCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        cacheCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
        cacheCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
        cacheCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cacheCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        return cacheCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getAllXDayOfMonth(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek) {
        final int ONE_WEEK = 7;
        int firstDay = getFirstXDayOfMonth(year, month, dayOfWeek);
        List<Integer> xDays = new ArrayList<>();
        xDays.add(firstDay);

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, firstDay);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ONE_WEEK); // adding 1 Week
        while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
            xDays.add(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ONE_WEEK); // adding 1 Week
        }

        return xDays;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mYear);
        dest.writeInt(mMonth);
        dest.writeInt(mDayOfWeek);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MondaysOutValidator> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MondaysOutValidator>() {

        @Override
        public MondaysOutValidator createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new MondaysOutValidator(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public MondaysOutValidator[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MondaysOutValidator[size];
        }
    };


}
```

Then use this validator to build [`CalendarConstraints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints) in order to apply these constraints on the calendar dates

```
/*
 * Limit selectable range to days other than Mondays of the month
 */
private CalendarConstraints.Builder mondayDisableConstraints() {
    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilderRange = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(new MondaysOutValidator(2020, Calendar.FEBRUARY, Calendar.MONDAY));
    return constraintsBuilderRange;
}
```

And finally build your `MaterialDatePicker` in your activity/fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builderRange = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
    builderRange.setCalendarConstraints(mondayDisableConstraints().build());
    builderRange.setTitleText("Select Date Range");
    MaterialDatePicker<Long> pickerRange = builderRange.build();
    pickerRange.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), pickerRange.toString());

}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Wish that can help you out, and welcome for further support.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to show datepicker without days

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
        RacingRsActivity.this,
        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                dateRc.setText(DateUtil.getCalendarHeaderDate(getDateFromDatePicker(view)));
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
            }
        },
        mYear, mMonth, mDay);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: without everyday?

Comment: only pick month and year.

Comment: no i want my calendar have (day,month,year) but disable some specific days for example(Sunday,Wednesday,Friday) or any other days that i want in my array