# Disable Saturdays and Sundays from DatePicker Andorid

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I need to disable past dates and weekends as well in my datePicker. I am using Kotlin.

For past dates this line is working fine

```
//Disable past dates
datePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate = cal.timeInMillis
```

https://www.freakyjolly.com/android-material-datepicker-and-timepicker-by-wdullaer-tutorial-by-example/

Here on this link I've found how to disable Saturday and Sunday, but for this line

```
 datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
```

I do not have the option to select setDisabledDays or something similar like that from the datePicker, and I thought that had changed since 2019 (the post is posted then). Do you have any idea how should I specify the days that I need to disable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you Disable Certain Days on a Datepicker - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454711/how-do-you-disable-certain-days-on-a-datepicker-android)

Comment: You can probably consider [MaterialDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490181/android-studio-disable-days-from-date-picker/61147318#61147318)

Comment: @KaranSharma yes thanks, but on the suggestion by mistake I clicked no

Comment: @Zain Yes that was what I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead. You have to pass array of `Calendar` as an parameter which contains all the select-able dates.

```java
datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

EDIT: Since you do not have the library. You need to add the dependencies as follows in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
}
```

You also need to add the `Java8` compatibility

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

You can find the necessary info here.

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: the extensions setSeletableDays and setDisabledDays are not available and that's the problem

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Can you paste the dependencies?

Comment: I am using only this
import android.app.DatePickerDialog

Comment: You need to add the library @Dipsy. This is a custom Date Picker. Not the default Android one which you have imported. I am updating the answer. Please check.

Comment: Yes this is working, thank you !