# How to highlight dates in android datepicker?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

How to highlight dates in Android datepicker like is on the picture below? On the internet, I founded few solutions but they don't use "original" Android datepicker. Is there some solution where I can edit Android datepicker, that I am already using?

[image: Datepicker with highlighted dates]

Comment: Thats a custom date picker. its not possible with conventional date picker dialog But might  possible with `MaterialDatePicker` . You can check `MaterialDatePicker` for this if it does not support then u need to find out some third party lib or create your own picker .

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, where can I find some documentation about MaterialDatePicker ?

Comment: What you can do with MaterialDatePicker is select a range, not select specific days and highlight these.

Comment: Ok, is there some way to disable the dates that I choose in official DatePicker?

Comment: @MichaelA. consider marking and upvoting my answer if it helped you, I guess is detailed enough to close this question, and since you are doing more question you should close this one, where the main question is already solved and open a new one and link me that new question if you want but do not do the [`chameleon question`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 3):

The official [`DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) Android Component, does not support this feature, that's why everyone is creating it's custom view or using a library to do so.

As @ADM said, there's also the `MaterialDatePicker` which contains more functionality than the *old one*, you can check this [material design post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/material-design-date-picker-in-android/) to get an idea of what you can do.

And for more information [`MaterialDatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.Builder#setSelection(S)) documentation.

### Edit

To disable dates you should use [`MaterialDatePicker - CalendarConstraints.DateValidator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints.DateValidator), where you can set the dates you want to *disable* or *enable*. You don't have to create a custom class in this case but you should create your own implementation of this, you should `override` the [`isValid(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/CalendarConstraints.DateValidator#isValid(long))method and there you choose the days you want to show as *enabled* or *disabled*.

An example of the code you should write is written on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147318/4385913

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387252/is-it-possible-to-add-a-dot-below-day-on-android-material-datepicker/73082637#73082637) - it's now possible to highlight the background of valid dates in Material DatePicker by extending the `DayViewDecorator` class.

There is [an official implementation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/BackgroundHighlightDecorator.java) in the material catalog.

The very simplified version goes something like:

```
class BackgroundHighlightDecorator extends DayViewDecorator {

    private final List<Date> myDates = /* your valid dates */;

    private ColorStateList backgroundHighlightColor;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Context context) {
    
      int highlightColor = Color.BLUE;
      backgroundHighlightColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(highlightColor);

    }

    @Override
    public ColorStateList getBackgroundColor(Context context, int year, int month, int day, boolean valid, boolean selected) {
        return valid && !selected && shouldShowHighlight(year, month, day)
        ? backgroundHighlightColor
        : null;
     }

     private boolean shouldShowHighlight(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (/* your condition for validity */) {
                return true;
        } else {
      
            return false;
         }
    }



    /** CREATOR code goes here **/
}
```