Android Jetpack Compose Material 3 DatePicker Highlight multiple specific Days
I use Jetpack Compose and the Material 3 DatePicker.
Is it somehow possible to Highlight specific days in specific colors??
DatePickerDialog(
               ...
            ) {
                DatePicker(state = datePickerState)
            }

I want specific days to be highlighted with a specific color.

There are some reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281693/how-to-highlight-dates-in-android-datepicker

As of now, the Material 3 DatePicker in Jetpack Compose doesn't natively support highlighting specific days with different colors. However, you can achieve this by creating a custom solution that overrides the DatePicker behavior.

Is there any tip, that you can give me to do that? I thik i need to override the function "Day" of the material3\DatePicker.kt
How can I do this?
